# Getting Error: The component for route 'Books' must be a React component. For example: import MyScreen from './MyScreen';

Tags: react-native, components

Getting the following error:
The component for route 'Books' must be a React component. For example:
import MyScreen from './MyScreen';
But i'm not even using react-navigation in this screen.

https://snack.expo.io/@ganiyat1/colorful-thrills

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import MaterialTabs from 'react-native-material-tabs';

const Book = () => {
  const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <MaterialTabs
        items={['New Releases', 'All', 'BOM']}
        selectedIndex={selectedTab}
        onChange={setSelectedTab}
        barColor="#1fbcd2"
        indicatorColor="#ff914d"
        activeTextColor="white"
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not exporting the Book component.

In the book component, either add `export default Book` to the bottom, or do `export const Book...`.  You also need to change the import to for a default export

```
import Book from './components/Books';
```

or

```
import { Book } from './components/Books';
```

if you do a named export (export const Book).